# python script to write output into a file iteratively

Tags: python, xml, file, io

First of all I am a newbie, and has no background on coding.

i am trying to create a python script that will create an xml api file which can be used later,

i have a csv file where each line is for one api call. I might have 200+ such lines. 
I am trying to read one line at time and print the xml data into a file, lets say file-1.xml

I can print the data with out any issues, but I could not find a way to redirect this output a file which should be named iteratively (e.g for i in range(1..200) or something)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        length=len(row)
        print """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <value>
       <array>
        <data>
         <value><i4>%s</i4></value>
         <value><i4>%s</i4></value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value><i4>%s</i4></value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value>%s</value>
         <value><i4>%s</i4></value>
         <value>%s</value>
        </data>
       </array>
      </value>
     </member>
    </struct>
   </value>
  </param>
 </params>
</methodCall>
                    """ % tuple(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv.reader` class has a line number attribute for each row: `line_num`. Simply use `reader.line_num` as part of the file name like

```
for row in reader:
    with open('file-{0}.xml'.format(reader.line_num), 'w+') as out:
        xml_template = "..."    # Put your xml template here
        out.write(xml_template % tuple(row))
```

No fancy extra code needed.
This does assume, though, that each request is on its own, single line.

Also, with new formatting guidelines, it is customary to use the {0} and .format style of string formatting. So instead of `%s` all through your template and `% tuple(row)` at the end, use `{0}` and `.format(tuple(row))` at the end. Just a suggestion, though. See [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        with open('file-{}.xml'.format(i), 'w+') as outfile:
            outfile.write(pattern % tuple(row)) #for brevity omitted template
```

You just need to open the file and `write` to it, much like you read from files. To keep track of which number we're on, we'll use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)